# How to filter the records by iterating over a list with out duplicates in java?

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to fetch the records based on firstName, lastName. Both are not mandatory parameters.

If firstName exists and matches then add to list and similarly lastName exists and matches(20 records) then add to list. If both firstName and lastName matches then fetch the combination of them (ideally less than 30).

Right now the below code is getting the cartesian product of records. How can we avoid this and fetch only combination of both firstname and lastName ?

```
 List<Person> filteredPersonDetailsList = new ArrayList<Person>();
            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listOfPersonDetails)) {
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstName)) {
                    List<Person> filteredFirstNameList = listOfPersonDetails
                        .stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(Person -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(Person.getFirstName())
                                && Person.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    filteredPersonDetailsList.addAll(filteredFirstNameList);
                    }
                if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(filteredPersonDetailsList)&&  
StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName)) {
                    List<Person> filteredLastNameList = listOfPersonDetails
                        .stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(Person -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(Person.getLastName()) 
                                && Person.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    filteredPersonDetailsList.addAll(filteredLastNameList);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do more checks than necessary. How about this:

```
// defaults as the immutable empty list (can be also mutable ArrayList - up to you)
List<Person> filteredFirstNameList = Collections.emptyList();     

// does it make sense to search for the first/last names?
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstName) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName)) {
    filteredFirstNameList = listOfPersonDetails
        .stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(p->                                          // something to compare?
             StringUtils.isNotBlank(p.getFirstName()) && 
             StringUtils.isNotBlank(p.getLastName()))
        .filter(p->                                          // the actual comparison
             p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName) && 
             p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems working to me:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("first1", "last1"));
        persons.add(new Person(null, "last2"));
        persons.add(new Person("first1", null));
        persons.add(new Person("first2", "last2"));
        persons.add(new Person("first3", "last3"));
        persons.add(new Person(null, null));
        persons.add(null);

List<Person> filteredPersons = persons.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(getFirstNamePredicate("first1")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        filteredPersons.addAll(persons.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(getLastNamePredicate("last2")).collect(Collectors.toList()));


// firstName Prdicate
public static Predicate<Person> getFirstNamePredicate(String firstName){
      return (person) -> Objects.nonNull(person.getFirstName()) && 
                         person.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName);
}

// lastName predicate
public static Predicate<Person> getLastNamePredicate(String lastName){
      return (person) -> Objects.nonNull(person.getLastName()) && 
                         person.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName);
}
```

Result:

```
[Person{firstName=first1, lastName=last1}, Person{firstName=first1, lastName=null}, Person{firstName=null, lastName=last2}, Person{firstName=first2, lastName=last2}]
```

Comment: Hi Shekhar .. I need only if both the firstName and LastName matches then filter to a list. I mean it should be similar to criteria in mongodb

Comment: Can u please reply on this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344273/how-to-filter-a-list-of-objects-based-on-filer-criteria-in-java