# How to filter a list of objects based on filer criteria in java?

Tags: mongodb, java-8

I'm trying to filter the firstName,LastName and dateOfBirth according based on some regex expression using critera in mongodb.

```
Query query = new Query();
        
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstName)) {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(ConstantsFIRST_NAME).
                    regex(".*" + firstName + ".*",  "i"));
        }
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName)) {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(Constants.LAST_NAME).
                    regex(".*" + lastName + ".*", "i"));
        }
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(dateOfBirth)) {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(Constants.DATE_OF_BIRTH).
                    regex(".*" + dateOfBirth + ".*",  "i");
        }

        return mongoTemplate.find(query)
```

How to replicate the same in java8 using streams and filters when trying to iterate over a list of objects ?

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("first1", "last1","dob1"));
        persons.add(new Person(null, "last2","dob2"));
        persons.add(new Person("first1", null, null));
        persons.add(new Person("first2", "last2", "dob2"));
        persons.add(new Person("first3", "last3", "dob3"));
        persons.add(new Person(null, null), null);
        persons.add(null);
```

Comment: Please specify a sample input criteria and the expected output.

Comment: Please specify the criteria you are looking for and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

For lists (and other collections), you can use `.stream()` to turn the collection in a stream. Then, you can use `.filter()` to execute certain filters on them. Afterwards, you can use the method `.collect()` to transform the remaining entries to another collection (you can e.g. collect them as a list again).

The method `.filter()` requires a `Predicate` which can be a simple lambda or a method reference. This predicate has to be true for all entries of the stream (the initial list) which should pass the filter.

Lets assume you have a `List<Person>` and every person has a name and an age. You want to get only the people with age 21 and older. The result should again be stored as a list.

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add(new Person("Karl", 14));
persons.add(new Person("Peter", 21));
persons.add(new Person("Susanne", 17));
persons.add(new Person("Kerstin", 30));
persons.add(new Person("Olli", 42));
persons.add(new Person("Josefine", 14));

List<Person> olderPeople = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() >= 21).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also combine several filters. This can be achieved with the classical way of combining booleans with `&&` or multiple sequential `.filter()`. You can of course argue about the efficiency of these two approaches. However, as [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24055107/10902231) describes, this decision can be neglected.

Answer (score 0):

You can have predicate combination like below:

```
public static Predicate<Person> getPersonPredicate(Person testPerson){
        List<Predicate<Person>> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(Objects::nonNull);
        predicates.add(p -> Objects.equals(p.getFirstName(), testPerson.getFirstName()));
        predicates.add(p -> Objects.equals(p.getLastName(), testPerson.getLastName()));
        //create single predicate with and conditions
        return predicates.stream().reduce(p -> true, (personPredicate, other) -> personPredicate.and(other));
    }
```